# How to inherit non-inherited attribute in c#

Tags: c#, wcf, asynchronous, named-pipes

Here is my situation:

1. I have a base class and 70 delivered class that are inherited from
   this.
2. I am implementing WCF named pipelines and these 70 class will be the
   clients.
3. Need asynchronously receive and send data

For third article i am using `[CallbackBehaviorAttribute(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]` attribute and it works when i insert it on a delivered class. But I should insert the attribute on base class and i won't spend my time to insert a new attribute or remove existing attribute on all delivered class. But when i inserted on the base class, it doesn't work asynchronously. Because `CallbackBehaviorAttribute` is not inherited attribute.

So how can i solve the problem that i mentioned above? I tried to create a new attribute that inherites from `CallbackBehaviorAttribute`, but it is sealed.

Client Code:

```
[CallbackBehaviorAttribute(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public abstract partial class BaseService : IDownloaderCallbackService
{
    public void connect_server_manager()
    {
        string address = "net.pipe://localhost/servermanager/";
        var factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IDownloaderServiceContract>(new InstanceContext(this), new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None), new EndpointAddress(address));
        server_manager = factory.CreateChannel();
        logger.Info("Client Connected");

        logger.Info(string.Format(server_manager.Ping(this.this_service_id, new byte[1] { 0012 })));
        logger.Info(string.Format(server_manager.SetLastRequstTime(this.this_service_id, DateTime.Now)));

    }
}
```

Server Code:

```
string address = "net.pipe://localhost/servermanager/";

serviceHost = new ServiceHost(service_manager);
NetNamedPipeBinding binding = new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None);
serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IDownloaderServiceContract), binding, address);
serviceHost.Open();

Console.WriteLine("ServiceHost running. Press Return to Exit");
```

IDownloaderServiceContract Code:

```
[ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required, CallbackContract = typeof(IDownloaderCallbackService))]

public interface IDownloaderServiceContract
{
    [OperationContract]
    string Ping(uint service_id, byte[] p);
    [OperationContract]
    string Pong(uint service_id, byte[] p);

    [OperationContract]
    dynamic SetLastRequstTime(uint service_id, dynamic data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by setting ConcurrencyMode as True in connection code block.

```
    string address = "net.pipe://localhost/servermanager/";
    var factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IDownloaderServiceContract>(new InstanceContext(this), new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None), new EndpointAddress(address));
    ((CallbackBehaviorAttribute)factory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors[typeof(CallbackBehaviorAttribute)]).ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple;
    server_manager = factory.CreateChannel();
```